# Udacity Sunshine app-lesson 1

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm going through the android dev training at udacity.com,following along with the implementation of sunshine app.I'm using android studio latest version for implementation.

I'm at the point to get where I'm supposed to get the mock listview and I am getting nothing on the screen and it was showing no errors.

Here is my mainActivity.java code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


           String[] foreastarray={
                    "SUN-CLOUDY","MON-SUNNY","TUE-FOGGY","WED-CLOUDY","THU_ASTEROIDS","FRI-HEAVYRAIN","SAT-SUNNY"

            };
            List<String> weakforecast=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(foreastarray));
            ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,weakforecast);



            ListView listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
            listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my content_main.xml code

```
     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

Here is my fragment_main.xml code

```
       <FrameLayout           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

  <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/listview_forecast">

  </ListView>

  </FrameLayout>
```

Finally here is my list_item_forecast.xml code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
   </TextView>
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Look my suggestion to you is don't use fragments at this point. Use simple empty activity and put the  code inside onCreateView of the fragment in onCreate method of the activity. Working with fragments and managing their life cycle could a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/1.06_attach_adapter/app/src/main). The attached link is for the relevant branch.

In your `content_main.xml`, you should just have a FrameLayout, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

By doing this everything will fall in place.

The reason you don't get to see anything is because the fragment is to be loaded into a container, which is usually a `FrameLayout`. When you call `add(R.id.fragment, new PlaceholderFragment())`, you actually add the fragment to the container whose id is passed in the first parameter, which as I said earlier is a FrameLayout. In your case, you are passing an id of a fragment, so it is unable to render inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you actually create 2 fragments here, one declared in XML, and another (empty) one added dynamically (not correctly, as pointed out by Eric B. in his answer) at runtime which hides the first fragment.

You should try removing the transaction inside your activity's onCreate().

Declaring a fragment in XML: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Adding a fragment at runtime: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html